# CodeIgniter, active records, JOIN help?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out why my JOIN is not working on a database query, I have two tables with a user_ID column, but when I return this it returns everything, not just the selected ones per user. What am I messing up any thoughts? Thank you!

```
function user_apps()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('apps');
    $this->db->join('members', 'members.user_ID = apps.user_ID');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;

}
```

Here is an image of the DB tables, and goal is to basically get the urls from the apps table of each user, 
http://cl.ly/516bd1e8aae62bd11773

Comment: whats it supose to return? would be helpful having the table structure for both and what fields you want to select

Comment: Ah crap forgot to link the image in sorry!

Comment: I second Gary's question. What are you hoping to return from the query? Whats wrong with what is being returned?

Comment: I put that answer in the question, hoping to return URL's belonging only to the user, right now it returns every URL for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a WHERE clause in your query. At the moment it is returning everything because you only have two users and they both have entries in the 'apps' table. 
If you add:

```
$this->db->where('members.first_name', $first_name);
```

And pass a first name as a parameter to the function then it will only return results for that user.

```
function user_apps($first_name)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('apps');
$this->db->join('members', 'members.user_ID = apps.user_ID');
$this->db->where('members.first_name', $first_name);

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query;

}
```

Comment: No problem. Of course, filtering results only by first name probably isn't very sensible in a real-world situation. I'd suggest making users register a unique username and then filter using that.

Comment: Yeah I did, I set their session data to have their user id also and pass that in. ;)